# Polygon support for ERC777

Tags: solidity, cryptocurrency

Does Polygon network support ERC777 token? I am writing a cryptocurrency with the intention of deploying it to Polygon.

Between ERC20 and ERC777, I am thinking of using ERC777 given that it is the upgraded version.

I see from https://faucet.polygon.technology that the test tokens I can receive are only ERC20, ERC721 and ERC1155.

Is ERC777 supported? Or should I remain on ERC20, or use ERC1155?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does support it. I just tested it and everything works, including the `operatorSend` function (which is the main reason to go for 777 instead of 20).

Here's one that is deployed and running fine: https://polygonscan.com/address/0x6f80d1a3ab9006548c2fbb180879b87364d63bf7#code